# VBA to extract unique values from list and count them on separate page

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, this has to be the easiest question ever, but I've been searching for awhile and can't figure this out. I have a very long list of values on sheet "Page1_1" (shtData) which I need to use to generate a list of unique values, along with a count of each unique value, on "Numbers". It's very simple to do manually by just copying to "Numbers" (shtNumbers) and removing duplicates, but the countif formula I use is very memory intensive, and bogs it all down. I have code to provide the unique list, but trying to get the count of each item is stumping me

Put simply: I need code to generate a list of unique values from "Page1_1" (shtData) A2:end of data, and put that list starting on "Numbers" (shtNumbers) A2 and down, then count occurrences and list the count in B2 and down.

current code:

```
shtData.Range("A2:A65536").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=shtNumbers.Range("A2"), Unique:=True
```

That code generates the list for me perfectly. I'd post what I've got for the count part, but it doesn't work at all, so I doubt it'd be helpful at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a Pivot Table?

Comment: I could, but I'd have to set it up every time I run this report, which is often. With a macro, I can just hit a command button and it's done. Of course, I also thought this would be easy to code, so what do I know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
With shtNumbers

    With .Range(.Range("B2"),.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(,1))

        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(Data!C[-1],RC[-1])" 'change data to actual sheet name

    End With

End With
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub SuperSimpleFrequencyTable()
    Dim C As Range, A As Range, B As Range

    Set A = Sheets("Page1_1").Range("A:A")
    Set B = Sheets("Numbers").Range("A:A")

    A.Copy B
    B.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Set C = B.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0, 1)

    With C
        .Formula = "=countif(Page1_1!A:A,A1)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

It will not leave formulas in the `Numbers` sheet.